# Difference between scatter-plot and a dotplot

Tags: graphing-functions

This question is now haunting me like anything, I am unable to understand , what is the difference between scatterplot and a dotplot? Is there any difference at all? or often people use them interchangeably. I have asked this question to several people , some say its same but some other say its different but no one able to explain any difference ? Sorry if this is a newbie question, but some one can explain this to me , I think that would be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dot plot is just a bar chart that uses dots to represent individual quanta.

So if you wanted to plot the number of pets per household, you might have 10 households with 0 pets, 20 with 1 pet, 12 with 2 pets, etc. Over zero, you'd draw 10 dots; over one, you'd draw 20 dots, etc.

A scatter plot puts a point representing a single realization of a tuple of data. For example, if you measured people's height and weight, you could create a scatter plot where one axis represented height and one represented weight. Each point on a scatter plot represents one person.